# How to check if the bowler is throwing instead of bowling in cricket?

Tags: cricket, technology

How to check if the bowler is throwing instead of bowling in cricket? Is there any technology for checking throw bowling in cricket?

Comment: Do you mean during a match, or during separate testing?

Comment: During a match and also in player debut .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we say the bowler is literally throwing the ball for example like this:

[image]
<sup>Source: [ESPNCrickinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/zimbabwe-v-pakistan-2011/content/image/531211.html)</sup>

then the umpire shall declare it as a [*No-ball*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_ball) imminently.

If we say the bowler bowls throw balls in [bowling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling_(cricket)) action. That means he is running and performing the same action as bowling like this:

> [image]
>   <sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bowling_action.png)</sup>

but not bowling properly (i.e. still throwing the ball), then if umpires catch such action during the match (**that is totally up to them**) they can call it a [*no-ball*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_ball) immediately. However, even if they don't catch such illegal bowling actions, the report for the illegal bowling actions is generated by match officials. If any illegal action found they submit the report the the relevant team manager. And process further. You can check the full procedure on [Illegal Bowling Actions <sup>PDF</sup>](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/525143d27cee1-18%5D%20Illegal%20Bowling_2013_WEB.pdf).

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question, which is how can you tell the difference, at all.

Answer (score 1):

**[Throwing in Cricket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throwing_(cricket))**

> A ball is fairly delivered in respect of the arm if, once the bowler's arm has reached the level of the shoulder in the delivery swing, the elbow joint is not straightened partially or completely from that point until the ball has left the hand. This definition shall not debar a bowler from flexing or rotating the wrist in the delivery swing.

**[Bowling Action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling_(cricket)#The_bowling_action)**

> A guideline was introduced to allow extensions or hyperextensions of angles up to 15 degrees before deeming the ball illegally thrown.

[**What Happens Next?**](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/cricket/rules_and_equipment/4404874.stm)

A bowler will be wired up with number of sensors, and Biomechanics experts -  Human Movement Specialists monitor the action.

**Update**

Quoting **[ESPNCricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci-icc/content/story/780269.html)**

> If the arm is bent at the onset of the delivery stride but remains rigid or does not flex or extend beyond the permissible 15 degrees during the duration of the stride, the action is not illegal. An action is only illegal if the arm flexes or extends beyond the permissible limit while in the delivery stride.

Comment: The guidline only applies in cricket played under the ICC regulations or those where the governing body allows it.  The law does not allow the extension of any amount.